# Create SQL query to insert a value if another one already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables. PositionCode, PositionCodeDetail, and Services

Service has serviceid, desc and status

PositionCode has codeid, positioncode, desc, status

PositionCodeDetail has positioncodedetailid, serviceid, and codeid

PositionCodeDetail is basically a list of potential services for a given position code.  I now want to add a new serviceid to each position code if it has an existing service code of 15.

Basically every time a position code has serviceid 15 I want to insert a new record that would have the same codeid and add serviceid of 20.  Positioncodedetailid is automatically assigned.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you already have a query to select the ones you want to duplicate?

Comment: SELECT distinct [CODEID]
  FROM [PositionCodeDetail]
  where SERVICEID = 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert  PositionCodeDetail 
        (serviceid, codeid)
select  20
,       codeid
from    PositionCodeDetail
where   serviceid = 15
```

With an additional check for an existing row with `service = 20`:

```
insert  PositionCodeDetail 
        (serviceid, codeid)
select  20
,       codeid
from    PositionCodeDetail pcd1
where   serviceid = 15
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    PositionCodeDetail pcd2
        where   pcd1.codeid = pcd2.codeid
                and pcd2.serviceid = 20
        )
```